# Diff filenames of two directories?

Tags: bash, diff

So, I've run the `ls -C1` on two directories:

```
mod@ux:~$ ls -C1 /bin | wc -l
165
mod@ux:~$ ls -C1 /sbin | wc -l
167
```

How to list only different filenames/commands and which directory contains them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `diff <(ls -C1 /bin |sort) <(ls -C1 /sbin |sort) |less`.

With `/bin` and `/sbin` as input to the command above, `diff` will append `<` to files unique to `/bin` and `>` to files unique to `/sbin`. If you need the `<` and `>` to be more informative, you can use `sed` to replace them with more informative strings:

`diff <(ls -C1 /bin |sort) <(ls -C1 /sbin |sort) |sed -e 's/^< /\/bin\//' -e 's/^> /\/sbin\//'`

Comment: Thank you! The second command did the trick, just with one more `sort` at the end:
`diff <(ls -C1 /bin |sort) <(ls -C1 /sbin |sort) |sed -e 's/^< /\/bin\//' -e 's/^> /\/sbin\//' | sort`

Answer (score 2):

You can have it compare directly against the directory structure:

```
$ diff /sbin /bin|sort
Only in /bin: arping
Only in /bin: attr
Only in /bin: awk
Only in /bin: basename
[...]
Only in /sbin: agetty
Only in /sbin: arp
Only in /sbin: arptables-compat
Only in /sbin: badblocks
```

You can add recursion too by specifying `-r`, if you like. If you don't want to know about common subdirectories, add `grep -v "Common subdirectories"` to the pipeline.